# A discussion of sql using 'set' or 'with' in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I found that the placement_policy function uses the 'with' keyword when making alter, but uses the 'set' keyword in other alter statements. Although it has no effect on the function, it breaks the uniformity of sql rules and makes users confused. Do you have any thoughts on use cases for 'set' and 'with'?